# JSON object - Accessing Values in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, react-native

In my React Native application I am using the RNDBModels package that is a wrapper over AsyncStorage. Currently I am saving a JSON object through RNDBModels and that works correctly, however accessing the data is proving challenging.

When the code is return from the `get` method, it is return inside a JSON Object and I would essentially like the values from the result, so that I can iterate over it for a list.

The returned result:

```
 { 
  '1': 
    { 
      name: 'Galaxy', 
      description: '20gram bars', 
      _id: 1 
    },
  '2':
    {
      name: 'Snickers', 
      description: 'Hazelnuts', 
      count: 2, 
      _id: 2 
    }
 }
```

And the desired outcome so that I can easily iterate over the objects in the array and then render a list in React Native.

```
[
 { 
    name: 'Galaxy', 
    description: '20gram bars', 
    _id: 1 
 },
 {
    name: 'Snickers', 
    description: 'Hazelnuts', 
    count: 2, 
      _id: 2 
  }
 ]
```

Any suggestions at accessing the values? I have tried using `Object.keys` and then subsequently `Object.values` to no avail sadly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) :

```
const data =  { 
  '1': { 
    name: 'Galaxy', 
    description: '20gram bars', 
    _id: 1 
  },
  '2': {
    name: 'Snickers', 
    description: 'Hazelnuts', 
    count: 2, 
    _id: 2 
    }
};

var array = [];

for (let prop in data) {
  array.push(data[prop]);
}

console.log(array);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0m51hya/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `lodash` just one line of code would work for your purpose

```
_.values(YOUR_OBJECT);
```

https://lodash.com/docs#values

It will make an array of values from your object.