# Display nested JSON object with different key-names but same value structure in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a nested JSON object in my react-native app which is in the following format, where key names are different but the structure of all values is the same *i.e. 
`{"value": "...", "label": "..."}`*

```
{
        "name": {
            "value": "Doctor Stranger Things",
            "label": "Name"
        },

        "qualification": {
            "value": "MBBS",
            "label": "Qualification"
        },

        "specialization": {
            "value": "Magic",
            "label": "Specialization"
        }

}
```

I have tried using `.map()` but since I'm new to react-native and ES6 I don't have a good grasp on its usage. The following code which I've tried is not working as expected.

```
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            {jsonData.map((item) => (
                <View>    
                    <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
```

**Assuming I have stored the JSON object in a variable jsonData, how do i access `value` and `label` of each key without having to access each value like  `jsonData.name.value` or `jsonData.qualification.value`?**

PS: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073518/json-object-accessing-values-in-react-native) may seem like a duplicate but I want to avoid using multiple for loops for storage and display purposes. And it's kind of different than what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Object.keys()

The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a  for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Try

```
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            {Object.keys(jsonData).map((item) => (
                <View>    
                    <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.label}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
```

more info on Object.keys()

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Yes, this is almost the correct answer. I wasn't able to directly access `value` and `label` using `{item.value}` and `{item.label}` but by using `{jsonData[0][item]['value']}` instead, I was able to. Why `[0]` because react was automatically enclosing the JSON object in an array element. I was able to access `{item.value}` and `{item.label}` as suggested by you by using `Object.values(jsonData[0]).map((item) ...` instead of `Object.keys(jsonData)...`. Thanks for your answer. Cheers!